# Select only columns that contain a whitespace as a single cell value

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe df:

| col_A (str) | col_B (i64) | col_C (str) | col_D (str) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 1 | c 1 | d1 |
| a 2 | 2 |  | d2 |

I want to select all columns that have a single whitespace " " as a cell value.

The result should be: [col_A, col_C]

My code so far:

```
df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8)).filter(pl.any(pl.all == " ")).columns
```

But this returns all str columns, ignoring the filter for " "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.filter()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html#polars.DataFrame.filter) is a row-based operation.

> Filter the rows in the DataFrame based on a predicate expression.

You could make use of [`.melt()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.melt.html#polars.DataFrame.melt) to reshape before filtering.

```
df.select((pl.col(pl.Utf8) == " ").any()).melt()
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────────┬───────┐
│ variable ┆ value │
│ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str      ┆ bool  │
╞══════════╪═══════╡
│ col_A    ┆ true  │
│ col_C    ┆ true  │
│ col_D    ┆ false │
└──────────┴───────┘
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked: df.select((pl.col(pl.Utf8) == " ").any()).melt().filter(
    pl.col("value") == True
)["variable"].to_list()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import polars as pl

whitespace_columns = []
for col in df.columns:
    if pl.any(col == " "):
        whitespace_columns .append(col.name())

print(whitespace_columns)
```

Iterating `col` is easier and sureshot approach and since its columns, they are generally finite in quantity.

Comment: Thanks but I get the following error: "ValueError: Since Expr are lazy, the truthiness of an Expr is ambiguous. Hint: use '&' or '|' to logically combine Expr, not 'and'/'or', and use 'x.is_in([y,z])' instead of 'x in [y,z]' to check membership."